# Пишу программу на SFML в c++ пишет Не удалось найти файл. Как исправить?

Tags: c++, sfml

Прикол в том что оно даже не собирает программу.
[image]

Comment: Там всё написано в тексте ошибки.

Comment: вы как будто при установке VS не установили Windows 10 SDK и зря вы русский ставите, ошибки менее понятные

Answer (score 0):

Не удаётся запустить программу, потому что программы нет, т.к. она не собрана. Ошибка сборки указана ниже и означает, что не установлен или неправильно настроен Windows SDK. Проверьте ваши установленные компоненты VS либо скачайте его вручную с сайта Microsoft.